# $\int_{J}(f(x))^{2} dx = \int_{J}(g(x))^{2} dx \Rightarrow \int_{J}|f(x)| dx = \int_{J}|g(x)|$

Tags: integration, proof-verification

> Let $f,g$ be smooth functions. Then the following applies:$$\int_{J}(f(x))^{2} dx = \int_{J}(g(x))^{2} dx \Rightarrow \int_{J}|f(x)| dx = \int_{J}|g(x)|$$ for $J$ interval.

Here is the proof:

Choose a subinterval $(a,a+t) \subseteq J$. Since $f,g$ smooth, we have $d/dt \int_{a}^{a+t}{(h(x))^2}dx=(h(t))^2$ and  $d/dt \int_{a}^{a+t}{(f(x))^2}dx=(f(t))^2$. 
By hypothesis  $\int_{J}(f(x))^{2} dx = \int_{J}(g(x))^{2} dx$, we have also $d/dt \int_{a}^{a+t}{(h(x))^2}dx=d/dt \int_{a}^{a+t}{(f(x))^2}dx$.
So we can deduce, $(h(t))^2=(f(t))^2$ for any $t \in J$, which implies $|f(t)|=|g(t)|$ for any $t \in J$, hence $\int_{J}|f(x)| dx = \int_{J}|g(x)|$ as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful with quantifiers.  What you proved is that if 
$\int_J f(x)^2\; dx = \int_J g(x)^2\; dx$ **for all** bounded intervals $J$,
then $\int_J |f(x)|\; dx = \int_J |g(x)|\; dx$ for all bounded intervals $J$.

Leaving out the **for all**, what you wrote says: if 
$\int_J f(x)^2\; dx = \int_J g(x)^2\; dx$ for some interval $J$, then 
$\int_J |f(x)|\; dx = \int_J |g(x)|\; dx$.  That is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not so sure what's wrong, but I admit I have forgotten to specifiy $J$ in the conclusion. 
I want only to proof that if for a (apriori) specific fixed interval $J$ holds $\int_J f(x)^2\; dx = \int_J g(x)^2\; dx$, then it also holds
$\int_J |f(x)|\; dx = \int_J |g(x)|\; dx$ for $J$ (it's the interval we have already chosen). Is this proof valid for that?

Comment: No, it is not, and the statement is not true.  For example, $\int_0^1 x^2\; dx = \int_0^1 (1/\sqrt{3})^2\; dx$ but $\int_0^1 |x| \; dx \ne \int_0^1 |1/\sqrt{3}|\; dx$.

Comment: Your right. Of couse I forgot that I need $\int_{I}{f(x)^2 dx} = \int_{I}{g(x)^2 dx}$ for any $I \subseteq J$ open.